# My html code can't reach my vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

This is my second day with vue. I was already using webpack and vue-cli, but I would like to understand how to make everything working within one file. I developed a code which works well, but I would like to refactor the code to have a component which I could later use to generate screen full of color changing tiles.

I tried `Vue.component('name', {})`, but with no result, because in the console I'm seeing `[Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.` and `[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <brick> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

This code works well:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>v pavle</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var vm = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        template:
          '<div v-bind:style="styleobj" v-on:mouseover="changebgcolor" v-on:mouseout="changebgcolor"></div>',
        data: {
          styleobj: {
            width: "100px",
            height: "100px",
            backgroundColor: "white"
          }
        },
        methods: {
          changebgcolor: function() {
            this.styleobj.backgroundColor = Math.floor(
              Math.random() * 16777215
            ).toString(16);
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And that code gives everything, but not what I want to see :(

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>v pavle</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <brick></brick>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var vm = new Vue({
        el: "#app"
      });

      var brick = Vue.component("brick", {
        template:
          '<div v-bind:style="styleobj" v-on:mouseover="changebgcolor" v-on:mouseout="changebgcolor"></div>',
        data: {
          styleobj: {
            width: "100px",
            height: "100px",
            backgroundColor: "white"
          }
        },
        methods: {
          changebgcolor: function() {
            this.styleobj.backgroundColor = Math.floor(
              Math.random() * 16777215
            ).toString(16);
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It may seem easy for you, but after 7h spent, there is nothing more for me, but just ask you on SO

Answer (score 1):

Okay I will answer your 2 questions. First and about data, it has to be a **function**. So you have to write it like that:

```
data() {
  return {
    styleobj: {
      width: "100px",
      height: "100px",
      backgroundColor: "white"
    }
  }
}
```

After that, your forgot to **reference your component** in your **Vue instance**. Try that:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    brick: brick
  }
})
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: There shouldn't be a colon after the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

1. Data must be a function like `data: function(){ return obj }`
2. Register the component using `components: {yourcomponent}`
3. You needed to use `#` in front of your color.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>v pavle</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      Hello App!
      <brick>Hello Brick</brick>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var brick = Vue.component("brick", {
        template:
          '<div :style="styl" @click="changebgcolor" @mouseover="changebgcolor" @mouseout="changebgcolor"><slot></slot></div>',
        data: function(){
          return {
            styl: {
              width: "100px",
              height: "100px",
              backgroundColor: "#b6d8a1",
              color: "blue"
            }
          };
        },
        methods: {
          changebgcolor: function() {
            console.log('changebgcolor!');
            this.styl.backgroundColor = "#"+ Math.floor(
              Math.random() * 16777215
            ).toString(16);
          }
        }
      });
      var vm = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        components:{brick:brick}
      });

      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `Vue.component`, you need to make sure that you have registered all components once you start rendering your app. At the moment, you first render the main app and then register the component, so swap those around

```
  var brick = Vue.component("brick", {
    template:
      '<div v-bind:style="styleobj" v-on:mouseover="changebgcolor" v-on:mouseout="changebgcolor"></div>',
    data: {
      styleobj: {
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        backgroundColor: "white"
      }
    },
    methods: {
      changebgcolor: function() {
        this.styleobj.backgroundColor = Math.floor(
          Math.random() * 16777215
        ).toString(16);
      }
    }
  });
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app"
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The data property on your component should be a function that returns an object. Why? Because otherwise all instances of your component share the same data, meaning all tiles on your app would have the same color.

```
data() {
  return {
    styleobj: {
      width: "100px",
      height: "100px",
      backgroundColor: "white"
    }
  }
},
```

2. You should first register the component before you fire up the Vue instance, just reorder your code and it works!